# Should you use #ifndef guard in forward declaration headers?

Tags: c++, header-files, forward-declaration

I have a simple header file where I forward-declare all classes in a namespace, eg.

```
#ifndef TEST_FWD_HPP
#define TEST_FWD_HPP

namespace a {
    namespace b {

            class A;
            class B;

    }
}

#endif
```

Should this file be guarded against multiple includes (`#ifndef` ...) ? Does this make sense for forward declarations only?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's usually good practice to protect header files like this. It isn't necessary in most cases where the file is only included once, but when a project gets complex, and header files are included in other header files it can help keep you sane.

If you only have forward definitions and function prototypes in it, then it usually isn't necessary, but as header files tend to acrete stuff over time, it's often worth doing as a matter of course.

Answer (score 2):

Multiple include guard don't only serve multiple declaration errors. You need to insert those guards in every header file, to avoid infinite inclusion loop.

Comment: What if file `X.hpp` includes this `test_fwd.hpp` but it has already been included elsewhere. Then it would include an empty file, so class `A` and `B` would be undeclared?

Comment: If test_fwd.hpp has already been include, so your guards are already defined, its that you are in the same compilation unit, so `A` and `B` will be declared by the previous inclusion.

Answer (score 2):

Just use a (formally non-standard) [`#pragma once`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pragma_once#Portability) and be done with it.

In addition to preventing multiple inclusions in the same translation unit, header guards or a `#pragma once` let the savvy compiler avoid re-scanning the file.

Comment: #pragma's are by their nature not portable

Comment: @Julian: how about, u know, *clicking on the link* in the answer? how about reading what you choose to comment on, before you comment on it? so on, thanks but no thanks really.

Comment: As stated in the link: In the C and C++ programming languages, #pragma once is a non-standard but widely supported preprocessor directive...

Comment: @julian: not formally standard does not mean "not portable". on the contrary, it's highly portable. in short, you're wrong, and you're now arguing against the facts after having familiarized yourself with them, just to uphold your premature un-informed conclusion. why bother.